# Take three tab separated tokens and make a Prolog "fact"

Tags: regex, perl, sed, prolog, nlp

Essentially, to go from `foo\tbar\tbaz` on each line of input to `'bar'('foo', 'baz').`

If any of the tokens contain a single quote, it needs to be escaped by a backslash:

`don't` --> `'don\'t'`

Details:

I have a file full of 'semi-structured' sentence components of the form:

```
the grand hall of the hong kong convention  attend by   some # guests
principal representatives of both countries seat on the central dais
representing china  be  mr jiang
britain be  hrh
the principal representatives   be more than    # distinguished guests
hong kong   end with    the playing of the british national anthem
this    follow at   the stroke of midnight
both countries  take part in    the ceremony
the ceremony    start at about  # pm
the ceremony    end about   # am
# royal hong kong police officers   lower   the british hong kong flag
another #   raise   the sar flag
the #   leave for   the royal yacht britannia
the handover of hong kong   hold by the chinese and british governments
the world   cast eye on hong kong
the # governments   hold on schedule
this    be festival for the chinese nation
july # , #  go in   the annals of history
the hong kong compatriots   become master of    this chinese land
hong kong   enter era of    development
history remember    mr deng xiaoping
it  be along    the course
we  resolve the hong kong question
i   wish to express thanks to   all the personages
both china and britain  contribute to   the settlement of the hong kong
the world   support hong kong 's return
i   wish to extend  my cordial greetings and best wishes
```

As you can see they're delimited by tabs. What I want to do is create normal definite clauses from this data, rendering them as:

```
'attend by'('some # guests','the grand hall of the hong kong convention').
'take part in'('the ceremony','both countries').
be('representing china', 'mr jiang').
```

So in the data as it is now, there is a verb phrase in the middle, which should become the basis of this new construct, and then the entity that is being acted upon should be the first parameter followed by the primary actor.

It's my hope that these can eventually be used in Prolog.

I guess not all of the data is fully formed, so maybe I can just throw that out.

I guess there's some kind of fancy perl script or regex, sed, type operation that can achieve this most effectively. I need to execute this on a massive file so I'm looking to optimize for efficiency, which is why I'm posing it here.

Comment: Is it an accident that `be` is unquoted, or should tokens that contain no whitespaces be unquoted?

Comment: aha, nice observation, i don't know, what do you think? maybe for continuity all should be quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed "s/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/'\2'('\3', '\1')/" filename
```

To keep tokens without whitespace in them unquoted, it would be simpler to use awk:

```
awk -F\\t -vq="'" 'function quote(token) { if(index(token, " ")) { return q token q }; return token } { print quote($2) "(" quote($3) ", " quote($1) ")" }' filename
```

As for perfomance, I suspect that the bottleneck will be I/O, not this program. If it does turn out to be a problem, though, you'll not want to mess around with scripting languages and knock together 20 lines of C++ to do it.

EDIT: In response to comments (what do I know about prolog, eh? :P), to always quote and quote apostrophes within quotes, awk is easier again:

```
awk -F\\t -vq="'" 'function quote(token) { gsub(q, "\\"q, token); return q token q } { print quote($2) "(" quote($3) ", " quote($1) ")" }' filename
```

But it is also possible with sed:

```
sed "s/'/\\\\'/g;s/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/'\2'('\3', '\1')/" filename
```

This will replace `'` with `\'` before doing the original thing. Shell quoting is involved, that's why it needs so many backslashes.

Note that the sed solution requires two tabs to be in each line. Looking at the test input, I'm not entirely sure that's the case, so awk may be a better bet for you.

Comment: Good answer (+1), but for Prolog, It is not only whitespace that will make the tokens need quoting. It is best (and easier) to always quote, but escape the single quote itself by a backslash, which your script does not do at the moment.

Comment: I think, might as well keep them with the single quotes, for continuity. That script works like a charm and it's so quick! @Boris I'm confused as to what your saying with regards to single quotes, you think better to use double quote?

Comment: @user3787253 I think it is better you get acquainted with Prolog at least a little bit before you proceed, because otherwise it is going to be difficult.

Comment: as per learning prolog better, that's certainly true. i also need to learn awk better, i guess it's not possible to pipe the resutls of echo or cat to awk?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake during copy/paste. Edited in the missing bit (`' filename` at the end of the second awk snippet). Without that, you'd get your shell to complain, sure enough.

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, consider tokenize_atom/2 (you need a recent version to be able to put in source arbitrary long text constants, and quote the ')

```
t :- Text = '
the grand hall of the hong kong convention  attend by   some # guests
principal representatives of both countries seat on the central dais
... rest of text...
the world   support hong kong \'s return
i   wish to extend  my cordial greetings and best wishes',
tokenize_atom(Text,L), maplist(writeln,L).
```

yields

```
?- t.
the
grand
hall
of
the
hong
kong
...
```

so you can use a DCG to 'understand' the text. It's far easier than passing thru external tools, I guess...

*edit* let's code Boris' comment:

```
file_2_statements(File) :-
  atom_codes('\t', Tab),
  open(File, read, S),
  repeat,
   read_line_to_codes(S, L),
   (  L \= end_of_file
   -> append([H,Tab,A1,Tab,A2], L),
      maplist(atom_codes, [Hc,Ac1,Ac2], [H,A1,A2]),
      P =.. [Hc,Ac1,Ac2], assert(P),
      fail
   ;  true
   ),
  close(S).
```

Comment: Some of the white space is a space, some of it tabs, which act as delimiters between the exactly three fields. It would be probably easier to read line by line, separate each on tabs to make three atoms, and use `=..` to make terms.

Comment: I had to edit the question because OP is not able to formulate it properly on their own.